# Converting orthophotomap to .ecw file?

Tags: convert, software-recommendations, ecw

I am looking for a method for convert orthophotomap (.adf files) to ERDAS .ecw file.

Have you got any ideas ?

Or maybe you have got any other idea how i can reduce a size of orthophotomap .adf files?
Now i have got 16 GB file I want to compress it to something like 3-4GB- is it even possible?

I read that .ecw is highly compressed for raster formats...

Answer (score 6):

You will need a paid Licence of the ERDAS SDK as the free (gratis) SDK is read-only. As an alternative try the Geotiff format with JPG compression.

For example, using the following two commands (but you have GUIs in QGIS, for example) to convert ECWs to TIFFs you get rasters that are more or less 30% bigger than then ECWs but look the same and are also as fast as ECWs

```
gdal_translate -co "TILED=YES" -co "INTERLEAVE=PIXEL" -co \
"COMPRESS=JPEG" -co "PHOTOMETRIC=YCBCR" -co "JPEG_QUALITY=70" -a_srs \
"EPSG:output_epsg_projection_code" $ecw $tif

gdaladdo --config COMPRESS_OVERVIEW JPEG --config \
PHOTOMETRIC_OVERVIEW YCBCR --config INTERLEAVE_OVERVIEW PIXEL -r cubic \
$tif 2 4 8 16
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use GDAL to convert ADF to ECW.  The [ECW driver](http://www.gdal.org/frmt_ecw.html) is not provided by default in GDAL, you need to compile GDAL and link to the external [ECW SDK libraries provided by ERDAS.](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/ECW)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Global Mapper software for that.

1. Load your raster
2. Go to File
3. Export raster format
4. Select ecw or some other and check boxes for creation tfw and prj